# Gridseed Mac OSX software

Tags: litecoin, mac, mining-software

Where can I find information on running a Gridseed miner on Mac OSX? Either BTC and/or LTC.

I'm looking for rather consistent information, by this I mean instructions with links that point to the software that works with the instructions or at least specifies the version of the software. One problem I see is that instructions are created and then the software is updated and no longer matched the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MacMiner](http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/), either the CPU miner window for scrypt mode or the FPGA/ASIC window for BTC mode and the GPU window for dual mode - the last two both use bfgminer
There's more information [here](http://fabulouspanda.co.uk/blog/index.php?post/2014/02/27/Mining-with-Gridseed-ASICs-including-DualMiner-on-Mac-OS-X) and Mac mining forums [here](http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/forum/) with lots of detailed info in some of the gridseed posts.

Answer (score 0):

For the 70Khs Dualminer USB miners, I found [this post](http://blog.nwoolls.com/2014/03/21/litecoin-mining-on-mac-os-x-dualminer-asics/) to work just fine.

If you're looking for help with the 300khs 5-chip miners on Mac, I'm stuck there as well. I can't find drivers for my Mac to recognize the "STM32 Virtual COM Port". I figure once I find those, the rest should be just like in the link above.

Comment: Hi @Lounge9, did you happen to find something on the 300khs for Mac?

Comment: @Walucas no, sorry, I don't have my rig anymore